# Disable Modern UI on SharePoint on-premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

How can we disable Modern view completely on SharePoint 2019 On-Premise?

Answer (score 2):

Pelase run the following PowerShell command to disable Modern experience view in the SharePoint 2019.

```
#Site Collection Level
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
$site = Get-SPSite http://sp19:81/sites/sitename/

#Disable modern Lists and libraries at the Site Collection Level
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true)

#Re-enable the modern experience at the site collection Level.
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Refernence:

- [How to disable the modern experience in SharePoint 2019](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/how-to-disable-the-modern-experience-in-sharepoint-2019/ba-p/303649)